# Is it possible for TestNg to show Cucumber Steps (And Hooks)

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, testng

I have a project with Gradle + Cucumber + TestNG + Spring. Everything is with last versions and runs smooth. The only problem I have is when I run tests from the Idea it shows me just scenario name (with ugly runScenario before name). Is there a way to change this reprezentation, want to have just names and also see step and hooks. With JUnit it was like this from the box)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I have found. If you want to run tests with TestNG in Idea and NOT from runner, than you can just use formatter options (add  *--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter* to the *program arguments* line in configurations)[image]

But, seems like there is no way for a beautiful represantation if you run tests using TestNG runner.